# Well-posedness of wave equations with time-dependent coefficient

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation, semigroups-of-operators

Let us consider the following wave equation 
\begin{array}{rrr}
y_{tt}=y_{xx}+a(t,x)y_{t} & \text{in}
& (0,T)\times (0,1), \\ 
y(0,t)=0\text{ , }y(t,1)=0 & \text{in} & (0,T), \\ 
y(0,x)=y_{0}(x)\text{ , }y_{t}(0,x)=y_{1}(x) & \text{in} & (0,1).
\end{array} 
Assume for example that $\left( {{y_0},{y_1}} \right) \in H_0^1(0,1) \times {L^2}(0,1)$ (resp. $\left( {{y_0},{y_1}} \right) \in {L^2}(0,1) \times {H^{ - 1}}(0,1)$).
In the case of time-dependent coefficients semigroups theory fails, we have to deal with this problem otherwise. I saw some books and I found that $a$ must be $C^1$ in time. Is this the optimal assumption? Because I could solve this problem by characteristics and I didn't need to this assumption, it was just $$a \in {L^2}((0,T) \times (0,1))$$.
Any suggestions?. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Who said that semigroups theory fails? I think you can do this in several ways with the theory. For instance you can apply  **Theorem  5.3.2**, pp. 168, Section 5.3 : Semilinear and Quasilinear evolution equations, in the book of **Ahmed Nasir Uddin:**

> Semigroup theory with applications to systems and control, Longman Scientific & Technical, 1991.

Comment: Thank you. I totally ignored that